# How to call a function without arguments in V8?

Tags: javascript, c++, arrays, parameters, v8

I found out how to call a function with arguments.

```
int argc = 1;
v8::Handle<v8::Value> argv[] = { v8::String::New("arg") };
v8::Local<v8::Value> result = function->Call(foo, argc, argv);
```

But I would like to call a function without any argument, therefore `argc` must be `0` and `argv` must be an array of zero length, which isn't possible in C++ I guess.

How to properly call a JavaScript function without arguments in V8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very easy, just use:

```
function->Call(function, 0, NULL);
```